# Genexus SmartDevice error just in android compilation

Tags: android, genexus, genexus-sd

I have a Genexus Ev3 U3 SmartDevice project, suddenly an android compilation error show off in the build list. The Genexus objects doesn't show any errors, the message is just appearing in process. I complile objects separated and they don't show compilation errors, jus when I add the dashboard is when the error shows off.. the full compilation listin is:

```
========== Android Compilation started ==========
Command: ant -buildfile "C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\IndicadoresFincas\build.xml" release 
Buildfile: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\IndicadoresFincas\build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-pre-build:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.3.4
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Android-SDK

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: IndicadoresFincas
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for IndicadoresFincas...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs
[gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.
[gettarget] Platform Version: 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for IndicadoresFincas...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'release'...

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-pre-build:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.3.4
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Android-SDK

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: google-play-services_lib
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for google-play-services_lib...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs
[gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.
[gettarget] Platform Version: 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for google-play-services_lib...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\UserControlLibraries\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\classes
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-release-prompt-for-password:

-release-nosign:
     [echo] 

-release-sign:

-post-build:

release:

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-pre-build:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.3.4
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Android-SDK

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: actionbarsherlocklibrary
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for actionbarsherlocklibrary...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs
[gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.
[gettarget] Platform Version: 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for actionbarsherlocklibrary...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\UserControlLibraries\ActionBarSherlock\library\bin\classes
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-release-prompt-for-password:

-release-nosign:
     [echo] 

-release-sign:

-post-build:

release:

nodeps:

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

-release-obfuscation-check:
     [echo] proguard.config is ${proguard.config}

-pre-build:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.3.4
 [checkenv] Installed at C:\Android-SDK

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: FlexibleClient
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for FlexibleClient...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Google APIs
[gettarget] Vendor:           Google Inc.
[gettarget] Platform Version: 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for FlexibleClient...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\bin\classes
     [echo] Creating library output jar file...

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
     [echo] Library project: do not convert bytecode...

-crunch:

-package-resources:
     [echo] Library project: do not package resources...

-package:
     [echo] Library project: do not package apk...

-post-package:

-release-prompt-for-password:

-release-nosign:
     [echo] 

-release-sign:

-post-build:

release:

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Found Deleted Target File
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 7 source files to C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\IndicadoresFincas\bin\classes

-post-compile:

-obfuscate:

-dex:
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\IndicadoresFincas\bin\classes
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\bin\classes.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\UserControlLibraries\ActionBarSherlock\library\bin\classes.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\UserControlLibraries\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\classes.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\sqldroid-0.3.0.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\picasso-2.5.1.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\IndicadoresFincas\libs\gxcommon.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.3.1.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\gxclassD.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\UserControlLibraries\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\gson-2.2.4.jar
      [dex] input: C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\android-support-v4.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-1153a44f9e0acd72115449c482e6ffce.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\bin\classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-48bb45053ee44f22b5fc72c9a4ab2f01.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\UserControlLibraries\ActionBarSherlock\library\bin\classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed classes-d003b224ddbaed5312caf3c712b4514a.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\UserControlLibraries\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\classes.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed sqldroid-0.3.0-95fbd363592c4f542cd65f62754a36b3.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\sqldroid-0.3.0.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed picasso-2.5.1-dc30351068b3cc2b2a94ca9168282ad8.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\picasso-2.5.1.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed libGoogleAnalyticsV2-0dd3f89583d90c2f2e32b8ea7de034a0.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed gxcommon-8b7a848746e829ded0c8ef34acc7f183.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\IndicadoresFincas\libs\gxcommon.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed nineoldandroids-2.4.0-786a01cf62ce8527ce7ff77618c99175.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.3.1-d9103c051e3e926a2011ed9ba4a43741.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.3.1.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed gxclassD-dc402e7ec6e4e15bcbe8da158adf9a9e.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\gxclassD.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-84660dbc3b6a27919a29bcaf4788f0cb.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed google-play-services-be6ea6d77c7906b65c948f106b23b81a.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\UserControlLibraries\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs\google-play-services.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed gson-2.2.4-3cc47bb5576f3bbcd392220c3718aa75.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\gson-2.2.4.jar
      [dex] Using Pre-Dexed android-support-v4-2340112556409dab9c2130623b013244.jar <- C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\FlexibleClient\libs\android-support-v4.jar
      [dex] Found Deleted Target File
      [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\IndicadoresFincas\bin\classes.dex...
       [dx] ERROR: el administrador ha deshabilitado la modificaci¢n del Registro.
       [dx] Merged dex A (65 defs/95,8KiB) with dex B (1216 defs/1489,6KiB). Result is 1281 defs/1945,1KiB. Took 0,2s
       [dx] Result compacted from 3020,0KiB to 1936,9KiB to save 1083,1KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (1281 defs/1945,1KiB) with dex B (237 defs/396,6KiB). Result is 1518 defs/1936,9KiB. Took 0,2s
       [dx] Merged dex A (1518 defs/1936,9KiB) with dex B (1 defs/0,4KiB). Result is 1519 defs/2394,5KiB. Took 0,1s
       [dx] Result compacted from 3268,9KiB to 2030,9KiB to save 1238,1KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (1519 defs/2394,5KiB) with dex B (14 defs/99,4KiB). Result is 1533 defs/2030,9KiB. Took 0,2s
       [dx] Merged dex A (1533 defs/2030,9KiB) with dex B (80 defs/103,1KiB). Result is 1613 defs/2634,2KiB. Took 0,1s
       [dx] Result compacted from 3585,4KiB to 2220,6KiB to save 1364,7KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (1613 defs/2634,2KiB) with dex B (87 defs/114,2KiB). Result is 1700 defs/2220,6KiB. Took 0,2s
       [dx] Merged dex A (1700 defs/2220,6KiB) with dex B (79 defs/246,6KiB). Result is 1779 defs/3039,5KiB. Took 0,1s
       [dx] Result compacted from 4095,2KiB to 2550,1KiB to save 1545,1KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (1779 defs/3039,5KiB) with dex B (73 defs/101,0KiB). Result is 1852 defs/2550,1KiB. Took 0,3s
       [dx] Merged dex A (1852 defs/2550,1KiB) with dex B (62 defs/84,0KiB). Result is 1914 defs/3250,5KiB. Took 0,1s
       [dx] Result compacted from 6098,5KiB to 4076,5KiB to save 2022,0KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (1914 defs/3250,5KiB) with dex B (651 defs/1477,5KiB). Result is 2565 defs/4076,5KiB. Took 0,4s
       [dx] Result compacted from 5251,8KiB to 4203,0KiB to save 1048,8KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (2565 defs/4076,5KiB) with dex B (102 defs/141,9KiB). Result is 2667 defs/4203,0KiB. Took 0,4s
       [dx] Result compacted from 5949,3KiB to 4775,3KiB to save 1174,0KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (2667 defs/4203,0KiB) with dex B (620 defs/603,6KiB). Result is 3287 defs/4775,3KiB. Took 0,4s
       [dx] Result compacted from 6116,6KiB to 4920,2KiB to save 1196,3KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (3287 defs/4775,3KiB) with dex B (153 defs/155,6KiB). Result is 3440 defs/4920,2KiB. Took 0,5s
       [dx] Result compacted from 6714,4KiB to 5375,5KiB to save 1338,9KiB
       [dx] Merged dex A (3440 defs/4920,2KiB) with dex B (444 defs/493,6KiB). Result is 3884 defs/5375,5KiB. Took 0,5s

-crunch:

-package-resources:
error: 
error: BUILD FAILED
error: C:\Android-SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:928: The following error occurred while executing this line:
error: C:\Android-SDK\tools\ant\build.xml:946: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
error:  at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.parseDependencyFile(DependencyGraph.java:180)
error:  at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.<init>(DependencyGraph.java:54)
error:  at com.android.ant.SingleDependencyTask.initDependencies(SingleDependencyTask.java:87)
error:  at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.execute(AaptExecTask.java:509)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
error:  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
error:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
error:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
error:  at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
error:  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
error:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
error:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
error:  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
error:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
error:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
error:  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
error:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
error:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
error:  at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
error: 
error: Total time: 23 seconds
Android Compilation Failed
Build All Failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error could happens if a previous build fails in the middle.

Please try deleting:

> C:\Models\IndicadoresFincas\SmartDevicesModel\mobile\Android\Main
>   Name\bin\

and build the project again.

Comment: Thank you... It really helps this deletion.